# db.execute (UPDATE TABLE) not working with Python

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

The SELECT command is working

```
engine = create_engine("postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/table")
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

username = db.execute(
            "SELECT person.username FROM person join contact0 ON person.id=contact0.id WHERE email = 
:address", {"address": address}).fetchall()
     
password = request.form.get("password")
password = generate_password_hash(password)
```

This command is not updating and I am getting a programming error, which assumes that the SQL command has a syntax error.

What could be my syntax error?

```
        db.execute("UPDATE TABLE person SET password = :password VALUES (:password) WHERE username = 
:username", {"password": password, "username": username})
        db.commit()
```

Comment: I am not! They are hashed. The last line of the first box is where I am hashing the update password.

Comment: The `VALUES (:password)` clause does not belong in your UPDATE statment. Simply remove it.

Comment: @GordThompson I tried to do that and just did it again. Here is the error that I am getting

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'RowProxy'

The statement is still incorrect. 



db.execute("UPDATE TABLE person SET password = :password WHERE username = :username",
                        {"password": password, "username": username})

Comment: What is `type(username)`? If it is a `list`, then what is `type(username[0])`?

Comment: This helped to some extent! Username is a dictionary, I wrote username[0] and the error switched to this ((Object of type RowProxy is not JSON serializable))

This error seems more reasonable)

Comment: Okay, so you need to keep drilling down until you get to the actual username *value*, which would be a `str`.

Comment: if you're getting an error while serializing the result, the db query seems like it already worked. This could be an unrelated problem after all. What are you serializing? You are probably trying to return the result over REST json.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think you need the "TABLE" in your update query. you probably copy-pasted it and the original used TABLE as a placeholder for "your_table".

try this

```
db.execute("UPDATE person SET password = :password WHERE username = :username", {"password": password, "username": username})
db.commit()
```

Also, since you're using SQLAlchemy, you could use the `query = person.update(**values)` statement, which can be extended with `query.where(getattr(person.c, k) == v)` for any amount of where statements and values to update very dynamically.

Comment: I tried this! 

db.execute("UPDATE person SET password = :password WHERE username = :username",  {"password": password, "username": username})

This is one command and I also did the same thing and added VALUE (:password) to the command.

There is still an error. It pains me that the credentials are being extracted from SQL, but I keep getting the queries wrong

Comment: put the command in a try: except Exception as e and show us what e says. This should really work...